# Временно изменить класс по onclick

Tags: input, javascript, list

Есть код:

```
<span class="clear" id="preview">Preview</span>
<select class="list">
    <option onclick="document.getElementById('preview').className="first' ;">Animation first</option>
    <option onclick="document.getElementById('preview').className="second' ;>Second</option>
    <option onclick="document.getElementById('preview').className="third' ;>Third</option>
</select>
<input type="button" class="run" value="Run">
```

При клике на опцию списка у елемента #preview изменяется класс. Проблема в том, что надо чтоб через несколько секунд (допустим через 2) класс возвращался обратно. Т.е клик>изменения класса>подождать 2 сек.>изменить класс в #preview на clear.

Есть еще кнопка .run , при её нажатии у #preview клас должен быть немедленно изменен на .clear, а потом на тот, чот выбран в списке .list, потом снов подождать 2 сек., и изменить обратно на .clear. Т.е клик>класс заменить на clear (в #preview)>сменить класс на тот, что выбран в списке>подождать 2 сек.>класс снова сменить на .clear

Comment: Пробуйте не вписывать всё в `onClick`, а создайте отдельную функцию, которая будет менять класс, а по истечению времени возвращать его обратно. Имя класса вводите как переменные функции.

Comment: Это похоже на задание первокурсника. Вы бы хоть более ясно изложили задачу. А то какой-то непонятный алгоритм тут высказали: там что-то должно произойти, а потом еще что-то, а потом еще что-то и затем еще, но как это произойдет - уже непонятно... В общем, попробуйте проще изложить суть вопроса.

Comment: Используйте [setTimeout][1].

[1]: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp